# SASS color methods change vs adjust vs scale

Tags: sass

I have read carefully the [SASS Color Module Documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/color#change)

But I can't understand the difference between change, adjust, scale color methods, Especially that in many times they return the same value.

Example:

```
color.adjust(#000, $whiteness: 10%);
color.change(#000, $whiteness: 10%);
color.scale(#000, $whiteness: 10%);
```

All those methods return: `#171717`.

Can anyone explain in detail the difference between those three methods?

Answer (score 2):

```
color.adjust(rgba(#8c2, 80%), $alpha: 10%); // => rgba(#8c2, 90%)    80% + 10%

color.scale(rgba(#8c2, 80%), $alpha: 10%); // => rgba(#8c2, 88%)     80% + (80 * 10%)

color.change(rgba(#8c2, 80%), $alpha: 10%); // => rgba(#8c2, 10%)
```

I used `$alpha` in this example because it is easier to visualize.

- `color.adjust` increases the current `$alpha` by 10%.
- `color.scale` increases the current `$alpha` by 10% of itself.
- `color.change` sets the current `$alpha` to 10%.

I hope it's clearer now.